# ajax form only works inline

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, I have following for ajax:

```
//Ajax 
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.my_popup_contact_open').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", 
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: ({ action: 'rh_contact_form_support'}),
                    success: function(data){
                          jQuery('.rhm_contact_support').html(data);                      
                },
                error: function(data)  
                {  
                alert("Error!");
                return false;
                }  
                }); 
         }); 
     });
```

For my `my_js.js` file, I have following setup:

```
//header script:
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
$(function () {     
    'use strict';

      //js goes here


    // Default line End
 });    
})(jQuery, this);
```

When I put the ajax js in the `my_js.php`, the function does not work. It only seems to work when I put the code inline at the bottom of php page.

Any suggestions to why it does not work when it is placed in "my_js.js"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot make use of any php code inside a js file.The easiest solution for that is make your my_js.js to my_js.php.Then if you want to use your js code inside my_js.php just use incluce/include or require/require_once in php..
Example:

my_js.php

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
$(function () {     
    'use strict';

      //js goes here

        //Ajax 
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('.my_popup_contact_open').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>", 
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: ({ action: 'rh_contact_form_support'}),
                    success: function(data){
                          jQuery('.rhm_contact_support').html(data);                      
                },
                error: function(data)  
                {  
                alert("Error!");
                return false;
                }  
                }); 
         }); 
     }); 
    // Default line End
 });    
})(jQuery, this);
```

index.php (Sample php file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script><?php require_once('my_js.php ');?></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

i hope that helps you. :D

Comment: Thank you! That solved the problem and learned something new! =)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the following line in the `$.ajax`

```
 url: "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
```

It works inline because php will find and parse the `<?php ?>` tags in your `HTML`, generating the correct `url` but it **won't parse tags in external javascript files**  so your url probably ends up unprocessed, performing ajax on an invalid URL and the server complains with a `505`.

To check if this is the case, open the browser terminal and search for said url in the external javascript file (under the **sources** tab if in chrome). If it's unprocessed, that's your culprit.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Didn't really think of the php line! :D

Comment: Glad that helped! I didn't include a solution because there's a number of ways to go about it. Personally, I'd output the url in a data-attribute if actually writing the url manually in the external javascript file won't do at all. I wouldn't recommend writing javascript in a php file...

Comment: hmm, could you show me a sample solution to what you suggest? thanks! =))